# Sharing NSDocument subclass between multiple NSWindowControllers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

I have a application that isn't currently a document-based application (because I thought it would be more trouble than its worth). However I've been thinking it may possibly be worth it now, but there is one issue I haven't worked out yet. Sharing `NSDocument` subclasses between multiple windows.

So do subclasses of `NSDocument` have to be tied to a single `NSWindowController`, or can I share these between multiple windows? The reason I ask is my applications files are likely to up 100MiB (or larger) and its also likely that a user will open the same file in more than one window. Also these files take a relatively long time to process, so allowing multiple windows access to the same `NSDocument` would be excellent. Also, the files are updated very quickly with lots of data, so synchronizing multiple instances of the same document would use a lot of CPU time.

Has anybody done this, or can it even be done with a Document-based application? Any advice on this topic is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How/when would these other windows for the same document be created?

Comment: Good question, there should always be at least one window. The rest would be upon user request. As for how, most likely by NSDocumentController (instead of the usual NSDocument), but I'm more than open to suggestions.

Comment: Yep, use a custom NSDocumentController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far this is the best answer I've found, which doesn't directly answer the question, but deals with many of the same obstacles I'm facing. Hopefully someone else has a better, more detailed and direct answer for me.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DocumentBasedAppWithOneWindowForAllDocuments

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the method `- (void)addWindowController:(NSWindowController *)aController` found in the [NSDocument Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/addWindowController%3a) to do just that.  There will be a lot of logic to let it know where to send what data, but this will at least give you control over several window controllers linked to the same document

Comment: I'm more interested in how a window can replace its NSDocument with another. I'm also wondering what class will be the window nib file's owner? And how would a window request a different NSDocument from the NSDocumentController?

Comment: When I had first looked into document-based projects a couple months back, I remember reading that adding windows controllers usually meant that you should subclass the window controller and set that as file's owner rather than NSDocument.  One document I read that was very helpful was in Apple's library, [Document-Based Application Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Tasks/FAQ.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Document architecture wil help you to manage multiple models - ie. if you want the user to have multiple models open simultaneously and be able to switch between them, it could be of benefit to you.

It doesn't stop you from doing anything, it doesn't make otherwise easy things difficult. Handling the Windows and GUI is still down to you, and if you are unsure how to structure this, it wont make any difference if you use a document or not.

If the contents of a window can change over time to represent different documents - what happens when many documents are open? This can be a difficult problem to solve, and i don't really mean from a technical point of view (changing a window's contents is as easy as window.contentView=newView, right?).

It sounds like you have many misconceptions about what the document architecture is and what it can do for you.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't read my question. The document-based architecture is very useful and I'd like to take advantage of its features. However its very tightly integrated and there are known obstacles with getting it to function outside of the usual document flow. The various classes are very interdependent and I'm wondering about the challenges of sharing an NSDocument subclass.

Comment: I read your question. What you want to do isn't in anyway 'outside' of the usual document flow. NSDocument has 1 method regarding GUI `– makeWindowControllers` - you can do with that anything you like.

Comment: There are more than a dozen NSDocument methods that reference UI interactions and window management, so obviously you don't really have much experience in this area and your help isn't needed any further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default is each document has one dedicated windows controller. But you can override

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers
```

to create your own windows controller and add them to the document as Slev mentioned.